# segmentation fault when reading data from a vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a vector called trees in which i store tree objects. When I try to access it and read a  field of one of its elements it gives me a segmentation fault. This is the code where I access it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < trees.size(); i++)
        {
            int yy = (trees[i].yPos - 100) / 50;
            int xx = (trees[i].xPos - 100) / 50;
...
```

the error occures in the line begining with int xx = ...

Right before this error I solved another segmentation fault that concerned reading a file twice to get the number of lines in a txt file. Maybe this messed up my code? Please help

Comment: The error is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: SDL_main(argc=1, args=0x663040): this is what I get in the call stack 
it directs me to the line I pointed above

Comment: the actual name of the object is "drzewo", im Polish by the way

Comment: the vector is called trees

Comment: As has been said, the error is most likely somewhere else. How do you fill this vector? Maybe you overwrite the size somewhere (i.e. you overwrite the member inside the vector object that holds the size,) or some part of the code accidentally messes up the vector's internals pointers.

Comment: In any case, unless the problem is something extremely trivial (e.g. you mistaking the location of the segfault), one sensible way to pinpoint the actual problem would be to start simplifying the code. For example, you can remove code blocks that modify `trees` and other local variables until the problem vanishes.